# PHP: Includes directory, strucuture, and/or path issue

Tags: php, path, web-deployment

Problem is very simple.. It would seem.

---

Error:

Warning: include(includes/navigation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sub_page\about.php on line 27

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/navigation.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\sub_page\about.php on line 27

---

I am redoing a site. Currently I am splicing it into PHP. Same way I have also ways done. Except this time I am making it more structured. Example of my code.

```
<!-- Start Navigation -->
<?php include 'includes/navigation.php'; ?>
<!-- End Navigation -->
<!-- Start Top Menu -->
<?php include 'includes/top_menu.php'; ?>
<!-- End Top Menu -->
<!-- Start Promo Menu -->
<?php include 'includes/pro_menu.php'; ?>
<!-- End Promo Menu -->
```

So lets that the file navigation is in includes folder which is located in the root. Lets say that the code above is on the services page which is '2' levels in. Not 1'. Typically i have it only '1' lvl of dir in so simply changing

```
<?php include 'includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

to this

```
<?php include '../includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

worked fine.

The above code is on the services page which is located at

/sub_page/services/services.php

If i moved the services.php file from the above dir path to 1 lvl close to root like so

/sub_page/services.php

and change the path on the include to

```
<?php include '../includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

it works fine. I need to be able to call the files from anywhere. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

---

EDIT: Will use the following as an example. I was pulling a path error on this line

```
<?php include 'sub_page/about_us/includes/meta.php'; ?>
```

I was able to use the following instead

```
<?php include __DIR__ . "/includes/meta.php"; ?>
```

to fix it. However if i tried to add or take away a directory level from the path it would again return an error. The same thing will not work for any of the other lines/paths.

before

```
<?php include 'includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

after

```
<?php include __DIR__ . "/navigation.php"; ?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to include a file (services.php) in other files which are on different levels. The included file itself includes some other files.

You must use absolute paths in services.php, e.g.

```
include __DIR__ . "/navigation.php";
```

Then it is irrelevant from which directory level you include services.php. `__DIR__` will always have the correct path of services.php, no matter where services.php is included.

EDIT: Maybe even clearer...

Assuming directory tree:

```
<htdocs>/index.php
<htdocs>/includes/meta.php
<htdocs>/includes/navigation.php
<htdocs>/sub_page/about.php
```

navigation.php is to be included by meta.php.
meta.php is to be included by index.php and about.php.

Paths for includes:

meta.php:  `include __DIR__ . "/navigation.php";`
index.php: `include "includes/meta.php";`
about.php: `include "../includes/meta.php";`

Any other file can now include meta.php with a path depending on its directory level.
The `__DIR__` in meta.php will always provide the correct path to navigation.php.

Comment: Thanks for the response although I do not fully understand how to implement the code you have posted. I'm assuming in the place of my previous include but how would I write it out?

Comment: It's getting there. lol. Your explanation has helped me clear 1 error up so far. Tweaking it to see if i can get all the paths right. gonna try before asking anything else. Will know in a sec. Thanks to btw.

Comment: Alright I edited my main question/post the edit is at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Set an include path for PHP to "look" for these files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php or use an absolute path.

Comment: How would one write out an absolute path in this instance?

Comment: Newish to some PHP concepts.

Comment: As Bernim pointed out, you could use `__DIR__` if on PHP5, or `basename(__FILE__)` in PHP4... then concatenate the relative file path.

Comment: I think you mean `dirname(__FILE__)`